# Is there any way to avoid "case" with some other thing in DB2 query for better performance

Tags: db2, query-optimization

please find the below query and suggest me to avoid case and rewrite the below query.

```
select A.ID, CASE B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN B.ABID
             ELSE B.XYID  END AS ABXYID
FROM Table_A A, Table_B B
WHERE A.PK = B.PK
```

please re write the above query for better performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey i couldn't found any other way thats why i came here. else why should i come here. ?

Comment: Is this really a performance issue or is it window dressing? Performance issues usually relate to structuring the predicate part of an SQL query. Use EXPLAIN to compare this to the COALESCE version provided in the answer below, I wouldn't expect there to be much of a difference.

Comment: 'Write the query for better performance'.... so impossible to just do that, especially on something this simple; it's not like there's much potential for the optimizer to get confused.  You _do_ have the proper indices, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you're looking for, but the [COALESCE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000780.html) function returns its first argument which is not null.

If B.ABID is also NULL when B.ID is NULL, then you could rewrite your code as follows:

```
select A.ID,
COALESCE(B.ABID, B.XYID) AS ABXYID
FROM
Table_A A,
Table_B B
Where
A.PK=B.PK
```

Oh, and you really should use a proper inner join:

```
select A.ID,
COALESCE(B.ABID, B.XYID) AS ABXYID
FROM
Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B
ON A.PK=B.PK
```

Comment: hi leons.. Thanks for your time.. between.. look at the condition when `(B.ID and B.XYID are not null and B.ABID is null)` .. then i Hope the above code fails..

Comment: Yes, the above code will not do what you want in that case. If you can't change the data or the table schema to make this work, you need to keep using a CASE expression.